# selectionStart and selectionEnd return nulls in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an Excel-style grid of inputs and I want to use the left right arrow keys to navigate between cells, but only when there are no characters in the input, or when the cursor is to the far left or right of the characters. So I've got:

```
console.log('selectionStart: ', currentCell.nativeElement.selectionStart);
console.log('selectionEnd: ', currentCell.nativeElement.selectionEnd);
```

where currentCell is an ElementRef. However, no matter where the cursor is with the characters, both of these always return null (if nothing is selected, both `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` should return the same integer value; if there is a selection, these should be different values, but there should always be a value). Any ideas on why this might not be working?

Answer (score 1):

I just tried changing the input type to text (it was number) and now it works. I'm curious as to why selectionStart and selectionEnd are available for a number input if they are not used.

Comment: If you have value for example 25 you cannot be inside, you cannot split as you can string. Here you can find tables for each input type: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#do-not-apply